# Highlighting UIImageView with grey color

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

How do it highlight the UIImageView when i touches it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imageView.alpha=0.5;` will do the trick.

**EDIT**
at **wizH** look at this image..
[image]

Comment: Tanks, that is pretty awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to place the image view into a second view with a colored background, then you can “highlight” the image view by setting its `alpha` below one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific image for the ***selected state***. Just add whatever effects you want to your image and save it as *imageNameSelected* and set the ***selected state*** for that name. This will work just fine!

For the dot you should create another question as it's not related to this in any way.

Comment: how do i set the selected state?

Comment: If you are using Interface Builder you can choose Highlighted: and then choose the picture you want.